# Java process restarting prematurely under runit

Tags: java, logstash, runit

I'm attempting to run Logstash under supervision with runit. My run script for Logstash is simply

```
#!/bin/sh
SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs exec /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/local/bin/logstash.jar agent -f /tmp/logstash.conf --log /var/log/logstash.log
```

If I run this script manually it takes 30 or 45 seconds for the process to properly start up and start doing work, but it will stay up afterwards for a couple hours. However, when I try to do `sv start logstash` it executes the script (and Logstash definitely starts because I see output written to /var/log/logstash.log), but after 15 or 20 seconds runit seems to kill and restart the Logstash java process.

I've tried setting the `-w` option, but it doesn't seem to wait any longer for the process to run.

How can I have runit properly let this Java process process run and only restart it when it dies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out not to be a problem with runit but with logstash. However, I was not seeing the error because I was not catching the output from the run script. Modifying the command to end with

```
2>&1 >> /var/log/logstash_runner.log
```

Writes stderr and stdout to a file. This allowed me to discover the real problem was that I needed to set HOME in my script so logstash could find HOME/.netrc to authenticate with the Heroku plugin.

Answer (score 2):

First, install `svlog`.  Using it is fairly painless.

Second, (assuming the service definition lives at /etc/sv) change your `/etc/sv/logstash/run` to say:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2&>1
SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs exec /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/local/bin/logstash.jar agent -f /tmp/logstash.conf --log /var/log/logstash.log
```

You are right in that `stderr` must be redirected to `stdout`.

Then, do this (adapting to your installation as needed):

```
mkdir /etc/sv/logstash/log
touch /etc/sv/logstash/log/run
chmod 744 /etc/sv/logstash/log/run
mkdir /var/log/logstash
chown log /var/log/logstash
chmod 775 /var/log/logstash
ln -s /var/log/logstash /etc/sv/logstash/log/main
```

This creates a log entry for the service, sets up a stub file to be edited, creates a directory to hold the log files, and provides a symlink for the logging service to divert output to.

Finally, put this in `/etc/sv/logstash/log/run`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
exec svlog -tt main
```

Restart your service with sv restart logstash and wait a few seconds...and you should have *two* processes listed, your `logstash` service and the `svlog` running with it.  All of the output from `logstash` will be fed into `svlog`, which in turn will write a log file to the `/etc/sv/logstash/log/main` symlink, which in turn drops off in `/var/log/logstash/current`.  Terminating the `logstash` service with `sv stop logstash` will allow any final output to flush into `svlog` which will write to disk before exiting.